# Changing the order of integration for double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to change the order of integration of the double integral:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}(y)}\sin x dxdy$$

I think it is:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\cos(x)}\sin x dydx$$

Am I correct?
And **what do you recommend** to do when it is difficult to draw the graph of the function
What is the way of doing the order change?

Answer (score 1):

Just decribe the set on which ou integrate. Here:

$$
\Omega = \{(x,y)|0\le y\le 1, 0\le x\le \arccos y
\}
\\=
\{(x,y)|0\le y\le 1, \cos 0\ge \cos x\ge y, x\in \arccos \Bbb R
\}
\\=
 \{(x,y)|0\le x\le \pi,  0\le y\le \cos x
\}.
$$
This gives you
$$
\int_0^1 \left[\int_0^{\arccos y} \sin x dx \right]dy
 = \int_0^\pi\left[ \int_0^{\cos x} \sin x dy \right]dx
$$

Comment: Note that the second line is underspecified: $\cos 0 \ge \cos x \ge y$ is true for many values of $x$ that do not lie in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: yep, I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are off on the $x$ limits:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\cos^{-1}y} \sin x dx dy
 = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{\cos x} \sin x dy dx
$$

**EDIT** In terms of visualizing, you can draw any curve but must find the points of intersection correctly. Like in your case, $y = \cos x$ crosses the $x$-axis at $x = \pi$ (not at $x=1$...)